# Waiting for the await to complete

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am updating multiple sheets in an excel file from Sharepoint.

```
 workbookRange = await graphClient.Groups[sharedGroupID].Drive.Items[newFile.Id]
                                  .Workbook
                                  .Worksheets[worksheetInvoicePaymentSchedules]
                                  .Range(rangeInvoicePaymentSchedules)
                                  .Request()
                                  .PatchAsync(tempWorkbookRange);
```

the worksheets in the excel are updated using variations of the above code, right after I get the content from the file

```
var invoiceFile = await graphClient.Groups[sharedGroupID].Drive.Items[newFile.Id]
    .Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

but the resulting content in invoiceFile is not complete, how do I force it to wait until all the PatchAsync updates are finished?

Comment: The call executed with await will always be finished before it continues to the next sentence, so if the data is not ready is not a problem with async/await but with the database, may be it has some delay before the data is available.

Comment: Can you check the implementation of GetAsync/ PatchAsync? If you have added await then it will wait for the operation to finish. So, the operation/ method looks to have the issue

Comment: The excel file has 3 worksheets, which are populated with data then I request the content and display the file to the user, but the file will only have the first worksheet filled and occasionally the second.  However if I go to the file which gets saved in Sharepoint it is complete, also when I am debugging which slows the process down the file is complete as well. Some sort of delay in Sharepoint commit the file changes??

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [session header](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel#sessions-and-persistence), the response times are faster. Without the session header, the save time is bit longer and this pattern is more suitable for write operation that doesn't require immediate follow-up. Session header helps with this situation - but not always (We are trying to rectify the situation. Especially the worksheet create operation is bit slower. Ideally, you'd want to have some 404/re-try built in to the logic.

Comment: thanks for the response I am finally getting around to fixing this issue, I have been looking all morning for a way to set the "persistChanges" to true using the .NET SDK... any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about .NET SDK's support of Excel APIs.. I can check and get back. However, the default is to persistChanges. So, you don't need to provide any JSON body in the requestto save changes.